# how to run gunicorn on docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I have 2 files that depend on each other when docker is start up. 1 is a flask file and one is a file with a few functions. When docker starts, only the functions file will be executed but it imports flask variables from the flask file. Example:

**Flaskfile**

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request
import json

_flask = Flask(__name__)

@_flask.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def flask_main():
    s = str(request.form['abc'])
    ind = global_fn_main(param1,param2,param3)
    return ind

def run(fn_main):
    global global_fn_main
    global_fn_main = fn_main
    _flask.run(debug = False, port = 8080, host = '0.0.0.0', threaded = True)
```

**Main File**

```
import flaskfile
#a few functions then
if__name__ == '__main__':
    flaskfile.run(main_fn)
```

The script runs fine without need a gunicorn.

**Dockerfile**

```
  FROM python-flask
  ADD *.py *.pyc /code/
  ADD requirements.txt /code/
  WORKDIR /code
  EXPOSE 8080
  CMD ["python","main_file.py"]
```

In the Command line: i usally do: `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 my_image_name` and then docker will start and listen.

Now to use gunicorn:
I tried to modify my `CMD` parameter in the dockerfile to

```
["gunicorn", "-w", "20", "-b", "127.0.0.1:8083", "main_file:flaskfile"]
```

but it just keeps exiting. Am i not writing the docker gunicorn command right?

Comment: What error are you seeing when the container exits?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I just went through this problem this week and stumbled on your question along the way. Fair to say you either resolved this or changed approaches by now, but for future's sake:

The command in my Dockerfile is:

```
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:app"]
```

Where the first "app" is the module and the second "app" is the name of the WSGI callable, in your case, it **should** be _flask from your code although you've some other stuff going on that makes me less certain.

Gunicorn takes the place of all the run statements in your code, if Flask's development web server and Gunicorn try to take the same port it can conflict and crash Gunicorn.

Note that when run by Gunicorn, `__name__` is not "main". In my example it is equal to "app".

At my admittedly junior level of both Python, Docker, and Gunicorn the fastest way to debug is to comment out the "CMD" in the Dockerfile, get the container up and running:

```
docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 my_image_name
```

Hop onto the running container:

```
 docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash
```

And start Gunicorn from the command line until you've got it working, then test with curl - I keep a basic route in my app.py file that just prints out "Hi" and has no dependencies for validating the server is up before worrying about the port binding to the host machine.

Comment: port 8080 or 8000?

Comment: The second example is just for debugging quickly and won't conflict - 8000 is what it is set to run at normally

Comment: in CMD 8080 or
-p anyport:8000

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem of not being able to connect. Gunicorn binds to 127.0.0.1 by default which is not externally reachable (such as through Docker's port forwarding).

Comment: @Fax your comment clarified things for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

After struggling with this issue over the last 3 days, I found that all you need to do is to bind to the non-routable meta-address `0.0.0.0` rather than the loopback IP `127.0.0.1`:

`CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:app"]`

And don't forget to expose the port, one option to do that is to use EXPOSE
in your Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8000
```

Now:

```
docker build -t test .
```

Finally you can run:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 test
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means: bind on all available interfaces, including localhost, which is also known as "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Thanks @kalou.net.

Please check it's now fixed

Answer (score 6):

This is my last part of my Dockerfile with Django App

```
EXPOSE 8002
COPY entrypoint.sh /code/
WORKDIR /code
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

then in entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prepare log files and start outputting logs to stdout
mkdir -p /code/logs
touch /code/logs/gunicorn.log
touch /code/logs/gunicorn-access.log
tail -n 0 -f /code/logs/gunicorn*.log &

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_docker_azure.settings

exec gunicorn django_docker_azure.wsgi:application \
    --name django_docker_azure \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8002 \
    --workers 5 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=/code/logs/gunicorn.log \
    --access-logfile=/code/logs/gunicorn-access.log \
"$@"
```

Hope this could be useful

Comment: what would this part look like on my end? `exec gunicorn django_docker_azure.wsgi:application`  can i use `exec gunicorn my_docker_image.wsgi:application` ?

Comment: that part is related to django app, i vern used flask so I cannot give you hints on it. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
FROM docker.io/python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=0.0.0.0 --chdir=./src/"
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "gunicorn", "app:app" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to run a flask app as well. I found out that you can just use

`ENTRYPOINT['gunicorn', '-b', ':8080', 'app:APP']`

This will take take the file you have specified and run on the docker instance. Also, don't forget the shebang on the top, `#!/usr/bin/env python` if you are running the Debug LOG-LEVEL.

Answer (score -2):

gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --bind :3000 --access-logfile '-'

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, try to explain what does the person who is asking is making wrong and why your solution works. Thanks