# docker ERROR: for nginx Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to `Docker` and setting up my first `Django` application using `Docker`

My application path looks like

```
app
 |- helloworld
    |- __init__.py
    |- manage.py
 |- static_cdn
    |- static_root
 |- config
    |- nginx
       |- nginx.conf
 |- Dockerfile
 |- docker-compose.yml
 |- requirements.txt
 |- start.sh
```

the contents of `Docerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# -- Install Pipenv:
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# -- Install Application into container:
RUN set -ex && mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# -- Adding dependencies:
ADD . /app/
```

contents of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "9010:9010"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static_cdn:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./static_cdn:/static
    ports:
      - "9010:9010"
    depends_on:
      - db
    expose:
      - "9010"
  db:
    image: postgres
```

contents of `config/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
upstream web {
    ip_hash;
    server web:9010;
}

server {
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    }
    listen 9011;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

contents of `start.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo --: Starting application build
echo --: Creating migration
exec python3 manage.py makemigrations
echo ------: makemigrations complete
echo --: Running migration
exec python3 manage.py migrate
echo ------: migrate complete
echo --: Running collectstatic
exec python3 manage.py collectstatic
echo ------: collectstatic complete
echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn helloworld.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:9010 \
    --workers 3
```

Now, when I build using docker

```
docker-compose up --build
```

It gives error as

> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed
> programming external connectivity on endpoint koober_nginx_1
> (8ea5c084a7283a16afbf136a73dc4b27d9cae35fe14d735b83199ad5d0e03431):
> Bind for 0.0.0.0:9010 failed: port is already allocated

I have followed few tutorials to create those Docker files and nginx conf file.

**1. How can I solve above issue.

2. Do I need to use `FROM ubuntu:18.04` with above configuration?**

> Edit 2

Now, it stuck after creating migration from `start.sh` commands
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't allocate port 9010 of your host for both services.
This is what you're doing in the `ports` section of declaration of service nginx and web.

Moreover, by default nginx will listen to port 80 and 443 for https.

You can keep it like that and publish to a different port on your host. See how to use `port` keyword in docker-compose :

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Maybe you want something more like that:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static_cdn:/static
   depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: .
    command: ./start.sh
    container_name: "web-app"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./static_cdn:/static
    expose:
      - "9010"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db: 
    image: postgres
```

contents of config/nginx/nginx.conf

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web-app:9010;
}

server {
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/
     }

location / {
    proxy_pass http://web;
}

listen 80;
server_name localhost;
}
```

Concerning your last question, you could go for an official Python image from the [Docker hub Python repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) or start from any other base image like debian:jessie-slim  from [Debian official repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/) or keep the Ubuntu 18.04 image

Comment: Thanks and I made changes same as your answer but now stuck after a command from `start.sh`.

Comment: It's hard to tell with your logs beacause all we can see is that postresql is alright and your application doesn't start. Can't you have more logs?

Comment: I figured out that `start.sh` file executes only first `exec` command and stops then after. Is there anything wrong in `.bash` file? I think it will be solved by making changes to `start.sh` file only.

Comment: Why are you using  `exec` in your last line? (```exec gunicorn helloworld.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:9010 \
    --workers 3```) and don't  just call unicorn?

Comment: Maybe you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925487/how-to-run-gunicorn-on-docker I don't know much about gunicorn and http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

Comment: can you tell me at what host it should be working. I tried `localhost`, `localhost:9091`, `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.1:9091` but it's not working

Answer (score 3):

For me, stopping/restarting the NGINX server worked.

To stop Nginx, use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

To start Nginx when it is stopped, use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

To restart Nginx, use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

To reload Nginx after making configuration changes, use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: works for me , it's preferable to disable nginx daemon from starting in boot : 
`sudo systemctl disable nginx`

Answer (score 0):

Following the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, I faced the same issue due to the installation of apache2 during the upgrade process. To resolve this, I uninstalled apache2, and everything worked smoothly. Since I'm using docker, apache2 isn't necessary for me. However, if you need both apache2 and docker, you might want to consider either using a different port for nginx or stopping apache2 while using nginx.

Here are the commands for stopping apache2:

- Stop apache2

  sudo service apache2 stop
- Uninstall apache2

  sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin

  sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2

Alternatively, you can find which service is using port 80 and stop it using:

```
sudo ss -tuln | grep 80
```