# getting NGINX to work with gunicorn web application

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, fastapi

This is my first time deploying a FastAPI + gunicorn web application with NGINX and the struggle is real.
My web app is running on an AWS EC2 machine using Docker.
What I've done so far:

1. register a domain with *godaddy* - let's call the domain *example.club*
2. Setup a DNS A record pointing to my server's public IP Address (via godaddy DNS management page).
3. created a *site-conf.conf* file and put it into */etc/nginx/sites-available*. The file has the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.club;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

4. Linked my *.conf* file to */etc/nginx/sites-enabled* with the following command:
   `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site-conf.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site-conf.conf`
5. Restarted my NGINX service using the command: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.
   When looking at the journalctl logs, everything looks normal:

```
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Nov 14 19:14:42 <server-address> nginx[16558]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Nov 14 19:14:42 <server-address> nginx[16558]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Nov 14 19:14:42 <server-address> systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Nov 14 19:14:42 <server-address> sudo[16537]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 19:14:42 <server-address> systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

**At this point, when opening up *http://example.club* I can see a "Thanks for using Amazon Linux" page**. 
To me, this confirms that my domain correctly points to my server's IP address + NGINX is setup correctly.

6. Now, all I want is to "connect" my NGINX proxy with my dockerized GUNICORN + FastAPI application (in order to expose my APIs to the world).
   To do this, I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
# add files to Docker environment
...
# run app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "127.0.0.1:8080", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "main:app"]
```

7. Finally, I build my image (`sudo docker build -t myimage .`) and run the container:

```
sudo docker run --name mycontainer -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -p 8080:8080 -d myimage
```

while making sure I publish port 8080 correctly.
The container's logs look normal:

```
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (1)
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Started server process [8]
2020-11-14 17:32:34,783 Started server process [8]
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
2020-11-14 17:32:34,783 Waiting for application startup.
[2020-11-14 17:32:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Application startup complete.
2020-11-14 17:32:34,784 Application startup complete.
```

I should also mention that I opened port 8080 for TCP from any IP address by updating inbound rules in the EC2 machine's security group.

**Unfortunately, when I try to access one of my APIs (http://example.club/<some-route-defined-with-FastAPI>)** I get the [NGINX default 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hoqe5.png).

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the NGINX proxy recognizing my routes?

Comment: In the `CMD`, you need to set the bind option to the special "all interfaces" address, `"-b", "0.0.0.0:8080"`; if you set it to 127.0.0.1 it will be unreachable from outside its own container.  See also [how to run gunicorn on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925487/how-to-run-gunicorn-on-docker).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, but I already tried using ```"-b",  "0.0.0.0:8080"``` and it didn't work either :(

Comment: BTW, the shell variables that I use within my site-conf.conf file are unpopulated (e.g ```echo $http_host``` shows nothing), I just copied the file from some online tutorial. could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, what I ended up doing was binding to "0.0.0.0":

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
# add files to Docker environment
...
# run app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "main:app"]
```

I also slightly modified my NGINX *site-conf.conf* (removing the *listen*s):

```
server {
    server_name example.*;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Finally, I installed python-certbot-nginx:

```
sudo yum install python-certbot-nginx
```

and ran it with:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.club -d www.example.club
```

**This setup allowed me to connect to my domain with HTTPS**, but I had one more problem: I **could still reach my webserver with HTTP by explicitly reaching for port 8080** (`curl http://example.club:8080/<api-endpoint>`).
To solve that, I headed over to the security group menu in the AWS website, and only allowed access to port 8080 from my machine's IP:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdQUZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the default config file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ (should just be called default) and in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and add `default_server` on your current config in the `listen 80` line.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.club;
    ...
}
```