# I expose ports in docker but it does not connect

Tags: docker, mlflow

I have a simple docker image (I post the Dockerfile at the end) and I run it with

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 5000:5000 -v $(pwd):/workfolder -it --rm stockpred
```

I am expecting to expose the ports 8888 and 5000.

Inside the container I do:

```
(base) root@41131b74043f:/workfolder# mlflow ui
[2022-06-06 10:59:24 +0000] [26] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-06-06 10:59:24 +0000] [26] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (26)
[2022-06-06 10:59:24 +0000] [26] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-06-06 10:59:24 +0000] [27] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27
```

so I go and open that address in my browser but I got

The connection was reset

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> ```
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
> ```

I thought that I could open the page externally. It must be something I am missing but what am I doing wrong?

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN pip install mlflow>=1.18.0 \
    && pip install numpy \
    && pip install scipy \
    && pip install pandas \
    && pip install scikit-learn \
    && pip install cloudpickle \
    && pip install pandas_datareader==0.10.0 \
    && pip install yfinance
```

EDIT:

It worked when I did

```
docker run --network="host" -p 8888:8888 -p 5000:5000 -v $(pwd):/workfolder -it --rm stockpred
```

Notice that I did not expose the ports in the Dockerfile.

Can someone explain me why this is working like this?

(I also tried exposing the ports in the Dockerfile and running like originally but it didn't work)

Comment: What is the `CMD` from the Dockerfile?  You need to make sure you set GUnicorn to listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address; see for example [how to run gunicorn on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925487/how-to-run-gunicorn-on-docker).

Comment: The dockerfile I am using (from a book on MLflow) is as it is written( so no `CMD`). Should I add something? (I ll check the link)

Comment: I made it work but I don't know why. Would appreciate an explanation