# Deploy a Flask App on Cloud Run GCP with python

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, soap, google-cloud-run

I am trying to create a Cloud Run that fetches photo URLs from a web service and then uploads them to a GCP bucket.

On my local machine, it works perfectly fine, but during deployment, I encounter this error:

**ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'main:app'?**

```
Folder
├── main.py
├── UploadPics.py
├── requirements.txt
└── Dockerfile
```

*main.py*

```
import os
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def get_pictures():
    args = request.args
    args_list = [arg.replace("'", "") for arg in args.values()]
    python_file_path = "./UploadPics.py"
    subprocess.run(["python", python_file_path] + args_list)
    return "Pre-processing done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

*Dockerfile*

```
# Use the official Python 3.9 image as the base
FROM python:3.9-slim


# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y file uuid-runtime zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install db-dtypes openpyxl requests cryptography==38.0.4

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 6 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

*UploadPics.py*

```
client = bigquery.Client()
storage_client = storage.Client()

sql = """
        SELECT DISTINCT IMMAT FROM `STOCK` 
        """

stock_immat = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
rows = stock_immat.to_dict(orient='records')

string_name = 'IMMAT'
immat = [row[string_name] for row in rows if string_name in row is not None]
print(immat)

def upload_to_gcs(bucket_name, df):
    ...
    file_blob.upload_from_string(csv_file)

@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3, wait_fixed=1000)
def connect_to_server():
     body ="""<soapenv:Envelope >
                <soapenv:Header/>
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <ajar:WS_Connect>
                            <Pseudo>login</Pseudo>
                            <Password>pwd</Password>
                        </ajar:WS_Connect>
                   </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>"""
    result = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
    result = result.content
    connect = pd.read_xml(result , xpath= "//ns1:WS_ConnectResponse")
    return connect


for i in immat:
    connect = connect_to_server()
    jeton = connect["Jeton"].astype(str)
    jeton = [str(x) for x in jeton]
    print(jeton[0])
    try:
        ...
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
        print("Erreur de connexion :", e)
    ....
    time.sleep(5)
```

The first `print(immta)` works, but I encounter the error afterwards.
I want to see if my logic is correct and if I can improve things to have a functional Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

**Mind the () at the end**

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#commonly-used-arguments) on running Gunicorn:

If you want to run the app directly, you use:

```
$ gunicorn main:app
```

If you want to use a function inside, you use:

```
$ gunicorn 'main:create_app()'
```

You should also fix the format of the CMD line to:

```
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:app"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried, but I am encountering the same error.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but from other things I read online, the CMD line doesn't look formatted. I could be wrong but do read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925487/how-to-run-gunicorn-on-docker) .

It talks about how to format the code for CMD:|

CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:app"]